# Entity Framework Core Recursively Include Problem

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that is including a list. And every list item has a reference to my entity.

```
public class Pack
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<Media> Medias {get; set;}
}

public class Media
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Guid PackId {get; set;}
   public Pack Pack {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, it's a classical one-to-many relationship.
I wanna fetch `Packs` from the database including `Medias`, therefore i wrote this code:

```
public List<Pack> GetPacks(){
   return _dbContext.Pack.Where(x=>x.IsActive == true).Include(x=>x.Medias).ToList();
}
```

When I get `Packs` with it's `Medias` included, I have a problem with recursively joining.
I am getting `Packs` with `Medias` but every `Media` again has a reference to the `Pack`. The result looks like below:

```
{ //pack
   Name: ...
   Medias: [{Id: ..., Pack: {Name: ... Medias: [{.. Pack: { ... Medias...
}
```

In short, When I include `Medias` while selecting a `Pack`, I am getting a recursively referencing problem.

What is the reason of this?

Comment: This is another perspective, but you can use JSON in this case. JSON is more fit for tree structures than table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[JsonIgnore]` above the `Pack` Property in your `Media` class.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public Pack Pack { get; set; }
```

When using your query the result will be

```
[{
    "id":"555d42a1-914e-4976-119b-08d84400ba5a",
    "name":"My Package",
    "medias":
    [{
        "id":"db406c89-ea4b-4e55-6621-08d84400ba50",
        "name":"New Media",
        "packId":"555d42a1-914e-4976-119b-08d84400ba5a"
    }]
}]
```

So you only have the `PackId` included and not the whole `Pack`.